# What's the most efficient way of combining multiple y = mx + b equations?

Tags: objective-c, c, math

I'm trying to write some unit converter code that essentially defines equations using the formula y = mx + b (so the "rules" consist of a multiplier and summand) and chains them together to convert between multiple units without having to specify each and every possible conversion combination (it uses a path finding algorithm to figure that out, but that's not part of the scope of this question).

Anyways, I've got things spitting out successive structs in the form of:

```
typedef struct {
    double multiplier;
    double summand
} ConversionRule;
```

What I'm trying to do is to "compact" multiple rules together. I can have a group of structs like so:

```
ConversionRule rule1 = { .multiplier = 2, .summand = 4 };
ConversionRule rule2 = { .multiplier = 4, .summand = 0 };
ConversionRule rule3 = { .multiplier = 3, .summand = 0 };
ConversionRule rule4 = { .multiplier = 1, .summand = 8 };
```

If I was converting the number "2" using rules 1 through 4, then I'd be looking at the following chain of equations:

```
double input = 2;
input *= rule1.multiplier;
input += rule1.summand;
input *= rule2.multiplier;
input += rule2.summand;
input *= rule3.multiplier;
input += rule3.summand;
input *= rule4.multiplier;
input += rule4.summand;
printf("The answer is: %f\n", input);
```

Which, in this example, would print a result of 104. However, I don't want to run through each successive rule individually, because sometimes there's a couple hundred of them and I'm really trying to keep down on any unnecessary math.

I've been trying to figure out how I can cram them all together into a single rule that can then be applied to the input *only once*, but I'm not sure how to do this (it's possible I'm not quite clear on what the terminology is that I'm looking for, if any).

What's the most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: add a new object `Converter` as a list of `ConversionRule` 's. and provide an api to iterate through the Converter applying ConversionRule's

Comment: Ever heard of the concept of arrays and loops?

Comment: alternatively write an api to convert two ConversionRule into one and combine all operations into one. ie. `output.CR = CR1.mult*CR2.mult, CR2.mult*CR1.add + CR2.add`

Comment: Are you asking how to do matrix multiplication (after projectivising)?

Comment: Assuming N equotations, use two arrays: `Y[N]` and `M[2][N]`.

Comment: Objective C, C: What language do you want this to be anwered in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to construct a rule that has the effect of applying two rules in sequence, you can do it like this: suppose you have two converters

```
Ax+B
Cx+D
```

If you apply them in sequence, the result would be

```
C(Ax+B)+D = CAx+CB+D
```

which can be rewritten as a single rule with multiplier `CA` and summand `CB+D`.

```
ConversionRule combine(ConversionRule r1, ConversionRule r2) {
    ConversionRule res;
    res.multiplier = r1.multiplier*r2.multiplier;
    res.summand = r2.multiplier*r1.summand + r2.summand;
    return res;
}
```

You can combine multiple rules in a chain by applying the same logic in a loop.

Comment: Maybe simplify with `double fma(double x, double y, double z);`?